# Use Imagic methods in ImagicDraw in PHP

Tags: php, image, imagick

I am using `Imagick` library for draw image over a image. I need to draw a box over an image, for this print image I am using `Imagick`, and for draw a image I am using `ImagickDraw`.

Printing a image with `Imagick` is working fine. And also `ImagickDraw` also working fine.

When I use `edgeImage` method in imagick will make the image as color inverted. Can I use `edgeImage` method in `ImagickDraw`?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillOpacity(0.4);
$draw->setStrokeOpacity(1);
$draw->setStrokeColor("rgba(62,46,45,0.9)");
$draw->setFillColor("rgba(62,46,35,0.9)");
$draw->setStrokeWidth(-2);
$draw->setFontSize(0);
$brightness = "-20";
$contrast = "-20";
$channel = "green";
$draw->pathStart();
$draw->pathMoveToAbsolute (10,0);
$draw->rectangle(0, 0, 170, 300);
$draw->pathFinish();

$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImage('images/men2.png');
$imagick->setImageFormat("png32");
$imagick->edgeImage(5);
$imagick->drawImage($draw);
header("Content-Type: image/png");

echo $imagick->getImageBlob();

?>
```

Comment: That is how edge detection works. Why do you want to run edge detection? What is the purpose/reason - is it for an effect? Can you share an image now you have few more points?

Comment: I don't want to use edgeImage method. But I need to use some Imagick methods. Can I use Imagick methods in ImagickDraw?